# XmlSerializer not serializing abstract class properties correctly

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have the following abstract class and a class which derives from it.  Although the properties are getting serialized, they do not specify the type and therefore when they deserialize, the properties are all empty strings.

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(DataList))]
public abstract class DataCommon
{
   public string Title {get; set;}
}

public class DataList : DataCommon
{
}
```

Xml looks like the following:

```
<DataList>
    <Title> ... </Title>
</DataList>
```

Shouldn't "Title" contain a type reference to the abstract class?  Is there something I'm doing wrong with the attribute or structure of the abstract class?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "Shouldn't 'Title' contain a type reference to the abstract class?"  I was able to serialize and deserialize the class above with `XmlSerializer` successfully, and the `Title` string was retained, so I can't reproduce that problem.

Comment: Does your serialized xml look like the example above?

Comment: It looks like this: `<DataList>
    <Title>This is a test</Title>
</DataList>`.  What do you want instead?

Comment: Maybe I misread a page and expected attributes on "Title".  I'm wondering if it is a Xamarin issue because I don't have the same issue with the same code in Windows 8.  I've tried a few serializers and they all have the same issue in my Xamarin project.

Comment: What attributes where you expecting on `Title`?  How would you like your XML to appear?  In my test case with `XmlSerializer`, your class serializes and deserializes successfully.